# Elements of the field $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^3-2\rangle $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am working the following example from Herstein's book "Topics in algebra" and some moments of the following excerpt seem very confusing and weird.

[image]

We are working with the field $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^3-2\rangle$. This is a field since the polynomial $p(x)=x^3-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, then the ideal $A=\langle x^3-2\rangle$ is maximal which means that quotient ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^3-2\rangle$ is field.

Let me ask my questions:

**1)** How it follows that $f(x)+A=(a_0+A)+a_1(x+A)+a_2(x+A)^2 ?$

If we use the addition and multiplication in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^3-2\rangle$ correctly we get the following expression. $$f(x)+A=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+A=(a_0+A)+(a_1x+A)+(a_2x^2+A)=$$$$=(a_0+A)+(a_1+A)(x+A)^2+(a_2+A)(x+A)^2.$$

**2)** Suppose we have $f(x)+A=(a_0+A)+a_1(x+A)+a_2(x+A)^2$ (although I do not understand why this is correct). If we put $t=x+A$ then we get $f(x)+A=(a_0+A)+a_1t+a_2t^2$ but NOT $f(x)+A=a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2$. Can anyone clarify this moment also?

**3)** Since we put $t=x+A$ we see that $t\in \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^3-2\rangle$.

Consider $t^3-2=(x+A)^3-2=x^3-2+A=A$ since $A$ is zero element of the field $F=\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^3-2\rangle $. In other words, $t^3-2=0_F$ but the expression $t^3=2$ seems to me meaningless. Am I right?

**4)** If $a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2=b_0+b_1t+b_2t^2$ then $(a_0-b_0)+(a_1-b_1)t+(a_2-b_2)t^2=0$ and we know that $t=x+A$. How it follows that $(a_0-b_0)+(a_1-b_1)x+(a_2-b_2)x^2$ is in $A=\langle x^3-2\rangle?$

Please help mo to answer my questions and clarify these moments! Would be very thankful for help.

Comment: For your first question recall that $A$ ( such a poor notation for an ideal) is an ideal. Therefore if you take $y$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$, then $yA\in A$.
In any case I strongly suggest you to change notations, and instead of working explictely with classes (i.e adding a $+A$ to your elements) only use the fact that you have a map $\pi: \mathbb Q[X]\to \mathbb Q[X]/A$ wich is a morphism of $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras. That is essentially equivalent, but you'll see things more clearly.

Comment: We usually equate the coset $1+A$ with the rational number $1$. After all, we want the field $\Bbb{Q}[x]/A$ to be an extension of $\Bbb{Q}$. To that end it must have $\Bbb{Q}$ as a subset, and this is achieved by identifying $q=q+A$ for all $q\in\Bbb{Q}$. You may have seen the same process in the classification of prime fields when it was proven that any field $F$ of characteristic zero has a minimal subfield isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}$. Then the isomorphism is constructed by starting with $1_F$. Equating $n\in\Bbb{Z}$ with $n\cdot 1_F$ et cetera.

Comment: Also remember that the kernel of $\pi$ is exactly $A$ by definition.

Comment: @A.Rod, yes I know that the ideal swallows up multiplication. Hence for any $y\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ we have that $yA\in A$. Sorry, but how it refers to my first question?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Unfortunately I am not familiar with field theory since in my book it comes after ring theory.

Comment: Well it is relevant because for instance $(a_1+A)(x+A)^2=a_1x^2+A$ because $a_1A^2+x^2A+a_1A^2+2a_1xA\subset A$ and two cosets have empty intersections or are the same.

Comment: Fundamentally what you're asking, is why if $I$ in a ideal in a ring $R$ the projection $\pi: R\to R/I$, mapping $r$ to $r+I$ is a ring morphism.

Comment: If $K$ is the field $\Bbb{Q}[x]/A$ you have $1_K=1+A$. Technically you are right (in part 2), and we only get that $$f(x)+A=a_0\cdot 1_K+a_1t+a_2t^2$$ where I wrote $a_0\cdot 1_K$ instead of the simpler $a_0$. In practice, when dealing with quotient rings of a polynomial ring over a field, we quickly want to "forget" the disctinction between a constant $a_0$ and the coset $a_0\cdot 1_K$. The scalar product in the latter is the scalar product of $\Bbb{Q}[x]/A$ viewed as a vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$. There are many ways to look at this. Early on it is correct to make this distinction...

Comment: @A.Rod, The last your two answers I can't understand unfortunately maybe due to my poor knowledge in algebra. We have that $f(x)+A=(a_0+A)+(a_1+A)(x+A)+(a_2+A)(x+A)^2$ but is it the same $a_0+a_1(x+A)+a_2(x+A)^2$ ?

Comment: (cont'd) just like you did. Later, it becomes an obstacle to continue to make the distinction, because you really want $\Bbb{Q}$ to be a subset of $\Bbb{Q}[x]/A$ (otherwise the notation becomes horrible). It is not unlike to the case of quotient rings of the integers. If the modulus $m$ is clear from the context, after a while the students are "allowed" to write $a$ instead of the technically correct $\overline{a}$ or $a+m\Bbb{Z}$ when they discuss elements of the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z}$. You will see this "abuse of notation" many times when studying abstract algebra

Comment: Ok, let met elaborate in an answer, I hope this'll make things clearer.

Comment: Similarly, in $(a_1+A)(x+A)=a_1(x+A)$ you can view the product on the right hand side as being the scalar product of the $\Bbb{Q}$-vector space $\Bbb{Q}[x]/A$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Indeed, the convention which author uses, namely that $a_1+A=a_1$ is quite strange for beginners that's why I have this question. It still bores me because I see it quite meaningless maybe due to my poor knowledge in algebra :(

Comment: I think of it as "notational shorthand" rather than "a convention". Believe me, all algebra students need to cross this bridge! Or, paraphrasing von Neumann, *In math (you don't understand things) you get used to things*.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Indeed, you are right! But it will be much easier if anyone can show how to answer my questions in detail. In my book (Herstein's) unfortunately he omits all these moments :(

Comment: You are facing the same obstacle in part (3). Namely $2_K=1_K+1_K$ is equated with $2$. Yet in other words, the author chooses to denote $1=1_K$ and as a consequence $2=1+1$. When studying groups you also often write $1=1_G$, or in the case of an additive group $0$, for the neutral element. Or, when extending from real numbers to complex numbers you don't make the distinction between the real $1$ and the complex $1$ even though in the sense of your question you really should. Also, in a polynomial ring you write $a_0$ for a constant polynomial even though you should call it $a_0x^0$.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, what you want is the follwiwng result.

If $R$ is a ring and $I$ is an ideal in your ring then $R/I$ has a unique ring structure for which the natural map $\pi: R\to R/I$ mapping $r$ to $r+I$ is a ring morphism. In other words $\pi(x+y)=\pi(x)+\pi(y)$, $\pi(1)=1$ and $\pi(xy)=\pi(x)\pi(y)$.

This is straightforward and should be proven in your textbook whatever it is.

In any case let's see how this explains your computation.

You have as noted in your book, an expression of the form $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+t(x)(x^3-2)$. You get appliying $\pi$, $$f(x)+A=\pi(f(x))=\pi(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2)+\pi(t(x)(x^3-2))=\pi(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2)=\pi(a_0)+\pi(a_1)\pi(x)+\pi(a_2)\pi(x)^2=(a_0+A)+(a_1+A)(x+A)+(a_2+A)(x+A)^2$$.

Notice that pretty commone to note $\pi(a_i)=a_i$ the reason for this is that the composition $\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb Q[X]\to Q[X]/(x^3-2)$ is injective as $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field. But even when it's not, we may use the same abuse of notation.

Now to prove the result I have mentionned well since the ring structure is putatively unique you have no choice. You need to define $(x+A)(y+A)$ to be $x.y+A$ and you need to check that this is well defined. In other words, take $x+A=x'+A$ of course this means that $x-x'\in A$ and thus $x'.y+A=x.y+A+(x'-x)A=x.y+A$. And ditto for $y$.

One remark, I don't think using the notation $x+A$ is in any case a good idea. What I prefer personnaly is to use representativess to define things. Which make thigs clearer I think.

In other words two elements $x,y$ in $R$ have the same image in $R/I$ iff they differ by an element of $I$. What we're proving here is that if $x,x'$ differ by an element of $I$ and $y,y'$ differ by an element of $I$ then $xy,x'y'$ differ by an element of $I$ and therefore you can define the multiplication of two classes by the class of the multiplication of any two representatives of the classes. The result won't depend on the particular choice of the representatives.

It should solve all your troubles.

I suggest you to use the map $\pi$ rather that the cumbersone notation $+A$, and in a little while you'll be able to drop the $\pi$ altogether and to pretend it is there even though not written explicitely.

Comment: Dear, A.Rod! Everything that you have written I knew in particular that in quotient ring the multiplication is defined via $(x+I)(y+I)=xy+I$. Reading it about 2-3 times I did found answer to my first question, namely that $a_1+A=a_1$