# Demonstrating that $F[x]/(x^3-2)$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

This is found in Chapter 3, on pp. 117 and 118 of Herstein's *Topics in Algebra* (1st ed.)

The proof involves demonstrating that for $F$, the field of rational numbers, $F[x]/(x^3-2)$ is a field. In Herstein's notation, $A$ represents the equivalence class $(x^3-2)$ in $F[x]/(x^3-2)$.

Herstein's first step involves using the division algorithm to prove that each element in $F[x]/(x^3-2)$ has a unique expression of the form $a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2$ where $a_n \in F$.

The section of the proof I'm having difficulty with starts off:

> consequently $f(x) + A = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + t(x)(x^3 - 2) + A = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + A$ since $t(x)(x^3 - 2)$ is in $A$, hence by the addition and multiplication in $F[x]/(x^3 - 2)$, $f(x) + A = (a_0 + A) + a_1(x + A) + a_2(x + A)^2$.

I can follow the first part readily enough; what I'm caught short on is how, essentially, $f(x) + A$ turns into $f(x + A)$. I feel like there's a simple step here that I'm just not seeing.

A similar question was asked here: [Elements of the field $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^3-2\rangle $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2808700/elements-of-the-field-mathbbqx-langle-x3-2-rangle), but the question was multipart, and the answer is split across several comments and a posted answer, and addresses multiple items. As a result I'm having trouble grasping it.

Comment: What is $A{}{}$?

Comment: What is $F$ also?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $A$ is the zero element in $F[x]/(x^3 - 2)$

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net $F$ is the field of rational numbers. $x^3 - 2$ being irreducible in that field, if I understand correctly, is a necessary condition for $F[x]/(x^3 - 2)$ to be a field also.

Comment: Don't answer that in the comments, [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4397375/edit) your question to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Herstein apparently combines a few steps for brevity.

Going from $f(x) + A = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + A$ to $f(x) + A = (a_0 + A) + a_1(x + A) + a_2(x + A)^2$ can be done in this fashion:

$f(x) + A = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + A$

$f(x + A) = f(x)$ in the field $F[x]/(x^3 - 2)$

$f(x + A) + A = a_0 + a_1(x + A) + a_2(x + A)^2 + A$

$f(x + A) + A = (a_0 + A) + a_1(x + A) + a_2(x + A)^2$

and since $f(x + A) = f(x)$,

$f(x) + A = (a_0 + A) + a_1(x + A) + a_2(x + A)^2$